# C++ callback with lambda function

Tags: c++, lambda, callback

First of all, I'm beginner in C++ so I don't know if the way I'm doing this is right or can cause some problem.

So, I'm trying to pass a generic callback to a function and then call member functions from different objects inside that callback. In this case, I'm creating a closure with a lambda function to capture the objects and then inside the lambda I'm calling they member functions.

Well, for example, the code is something like this:

```
// ...

void functionWithCallback(std::function<void()> callback)
{
    // Do some stuff ...

    callback();
}


int main() 
{
    SomeClass some_object = SomeClass();
    AnotherClass another_object = AnotherClass();

    std::function<void()> callback = [&some_object, &another_object]() {
        some_object.someFunction();
        another_object.anotherFunction();
    };

    functionWithCallback(callback);
}
```

My question is: is this a correct way or can it cause some problems or unexpected behaviors? Is there any more elegant way to do this?

Comment: i am reluctant to given an answer to "can it cause some problems" because its rare that this isnt the case with something in C++, but you definitely have to make sure that the objects are still alive (and you should delete them, why use `new` at all?), otherwise there is no obvious problem

Comment: You example code leaks memory, since there are no matching deletes. I would find it more elegant to just allocate the objects on the stack and capture them by reference. Also, be careful that the objects are still alive when callback is called (here, that is the case, regardless if you allocate the objects dynamically or on hte stack).

Comment: ... that being said, if you want your code being reviewed, perhaps https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the better place. Just make sure to post complete and working code there

Comment: btw why the tag spamming? Use the C++ tag for the current standard and the others if your question is about a particular version of the standard

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 It's just an example, in fact, where I want to implement this requires the object to be in the heap. I updated the sample code here to solve this problem, I just wanted to be objective. Sorry about the tags, I'm new here too, so I didn't know which tag to use. 

Thanks.

Comment: @n314159 I just wanted to be objective. I've updated the sample code to avoid the memory leak. Is this correct? 

Thanks

Comment: It is correct. But raw new and delete are not really modern C++ code. If you really want dynamically allocated objects, use `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: *where I want to implement this requires the object to be in the heap* Are you sure about that? Why? Also, if you need the object on the heap you should wrap it in something that takes care of the memory management for you. If you have specific restrictions on your code you should add them to your question.

Comment: I'll try to use std::unique_ptr. Thank you.

Comment: @super It's just a idea to use inside a simple game that I'm making. Actually I'm using QT to deal with the graphics... So as my classes inherit from QT classes i think is safer to allocate this objects on the heap. But, considering that I am deleting all objects at the right time there are no problems. Right?

Comment: To simplify this question and solve the memory allocation problem, I have modified object creation here in the example code.

Comment: @LucasMazz Right, if you manage the memory correcly there is no problem. It is however an extra comlication that you shouldn't have to deal with. The reason I emphasize it is since you often see poeple who are not all that familiar with `C++` use it just since it feels more familiar when coming from other languages.

Comment: I completely understand. It was a mess to me at beginning. Thanks.